# deploy Github public project (PHP) on dedicated server

Tags: php, git, amazon-web-services, github

my project is developed on github and now I want to deploy it to dedicated server, any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Just install Git on it and do a `git pull`? - Also, voting to close as to broad

Comment: but do I need to change any code or configuration to make it work properly or something else?

Comment: I don't know, how am I supposed to know what you need to change in your own code?

Comment: I dont have any experience with github so when I tried to download code from repo it gives lot of file and directories so if I do git pull does it only import code for application or whole repo?

Comment: Then it's probably a good thing to take a couple of tutorials and read up on what Git and GitHub are, where they differ and what they share.

Comment: I think thats good idea thanks

Answer (score 1):

1) Login to your dedicated server using SSH.

- for windows use putty
- for ubuntu and mac use terminal

2) install git on your dedicated server . [how to install ?](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-git-on-ubuntu-18-04-quickstart)

3) after that follow below commads :

**Clone the repository** : `git clone https://github.com/username/repositoryname.git`

**Go into repository** : `cd repositoryname`

after that if you add some new code in your code editor , use below command in **your local git repository** :

```
git add .                    // this will add your code to local git repo
git commit -m "code updated" // this will commit your changes in local git repo
git push                     // this will push your code from local git repo to github repo
```

after that go to ssh , go to your repository on your server and pull the latest code using :

```
git pull     //it will pull your code to your server .
```